# Class vs Struct - Which is best for Shared Instances?

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, swift3

Since, I have started using `struct`, I am wondering which is best among `Class` and `Struct` for creating Shared Instances.

> `Class` Example:

```
class Helper{
    func isNetworkReachable(){
        return reachability.isReachable
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
//Below taking as a Global Instance
let helperInstance = Helper()
print(helperInstance.isNetworkReachable())
```

In `Class`, as we can see that shared instance is created and it stays is memory till application terminate.

> `struct` Example:

```
struct Helper{
    static func isNetworkReachable(){
        return reachability.isReachable
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
print(Helper.isNetworkReachable())
```

In `struct`, the `static` keyword plays the main role as it also specifies that the instance will stays in memory till application terminates.

In short, I want to know which is best, `Class` or `struct` and why?

Comment: @LeoDabus What does Swift class vs struct have to do with Objective-C?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class

Comment: @rmaddy I want to know the memory status and performance, like which uses less and which is fast?

Comment: @rmaddy Also, as I am using `static` keyword to access directly, is that feasible or creating an object is better?

Comment: Your comparisons aren't the same. In your `class`, make `isNetworkReachable` a `class` method and it will be just like your `struct` and its `static` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok so writing `class` infront of every `func` behaves same as `struct` and `static`. So, now again what will be the difference between them? For that, I should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class?noredirect=1&lq=1 right?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788169/whats-the-difference-between-struct-based-and-class-based-singletons.