# Swift how to make the default initializer of a `struct` private

Tags: swift, initialization, singleton

We have struct single in our code like this:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: String
    static let sharedInstance = Foo(bar: "blah")
}
```

It works nice except that caller can still initialize another instance of the Foo instance with

```
let foo = Foo.init(bar: "blah")
```

Is there a way to make the generated initializer private?

---

We tried explicitly define the initializer like this:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: String
    static let sharedInstance = Foo(bar: "blah")

    private init(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}
```

It works, but it get a bit annoying because whenever we add/change a property, we will have to modify the initializer again. I like the way that the initializer is automatically generated and we don't have to write these boiler code. Is it possible?

Comment: An alternative would be to define only  `private init()` without parameters, and give all properties initial values: `let bar  = "blah"` ...

Comment: Hello @MartinR, is it even valid to implement the singleton pattern with Structs?

Comment: @AhmadF: Indeed. From http://stackoverflow.com/a/36788519/1187415: *''The main difference is that class-based mutable singleton works, while struct-based mutable "singleton" doesn't'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are noticing that implementing:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: String
    static let sharedInstance = Foo(bar: "blah")
}
```

is legal even without giving `bar` an initial value, why? because Swift Structs have a default initializer, called *the memberwise initializer:*

> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they
>   do not define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default
>   initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if
>   it has stored properties that do not have default values.
>
> The memberwise initializer is a shorthand way to initialize the member
>   properties of new structure instances. Initial values for the
>   properties of the new instance can be passed to the memberwise
>   initializer by name.

Meaning that if you tried to create a new instance of `Foo` struct, the compiler should -automatically- provide:

[image]

However, you can get rid of it by implementing `private init()`, but you have to make sure that all stored properties have -dummy- initial values (or maybe let them optionals...) because the struct no longer has an initializer for guaranteeing that the stored properties has values.

It should be similar to:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: String = ""
    static var shared = Foo()

    private init() {}
}
```

***Remark:*** I would suggest to stuck with *class* when implementing a singleton pattern, you might want to [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788169/whats-the-difference-between-struct-based-and-class-based-singletons/36788519#36788519) (Thanks to
[MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) for mentioning it).