# How do I verify incoming data for properties?

Tags: swift

In my model, I have a singleton class which will contain some global properties and methods. I think I've set up the class correctly but I need a way to verify incoming data for the properties. I'm trying to use `get` and `set` but these seem to need to return void. I can't use init because it's a singleton.
Am I missing something?

```
final class Globals {

    private init(){}

    static let sharedInstance = Globals()

    //MARK: Properties
    private var _peopleCount: Int!

    var peopleCount: Int! {
        get {
            return _peopleCount
        }
        set(newPeopleCount) {
            guard newPeopleCount > 0 else {
                return nil  // can't return nil here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can‘t return nil here"* - do you want to, though? Then change `peopleCount: Int!` to `peopleCount: Int?`.

Comment: You should use didSet instead of using a private property with an underscore prefix. `var peopleCount: Int? {
        didSet  {
            if let newValue = peopleCount, newValue > 0 {
                peopleCount = newValue
            } else {
                peopleCount = oldValue
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: if you really want to discard the oldValue `var peopleCount: Int? { didSet { if let newValue = peopleCount, newValue > 0 { peopleCount = newValue } else { peopleCount = nil } } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't define your variables as implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Your immediate error is that you cannot return a value in a setter, you need to assign the value to the variable there. If you want to mark an invalid value by `peopleCount` being `nil`, define `peopleCount` as `Int?` and assign to it `nil` when the check fails.

```
final class Globals {

    private init(){}

    static let sharedInstance = Globals()

    //MARK: Properties
    private var _peopleCount: Int?

    var peopleCount: Int? {
        get {
            return _peopleCount
        }
        set(newPeopleCount) {
            if let newValue = newPeopleCount, newValue > 0 {
                _peopleCount = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For most use cases, there is no need for the private backing variable, you can just use `didSet` to check the value before assigning it. Thanks for @LeoDabus for the idea in comments.

```
var peopleCount: Int? {
    didSet {
        if let newValue = peopleCount, newValue > 0 {
            peopleCount = newValue
        } else {
            peopleCount = oldValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use didSet instead.

Comment: thanks. Can I not preserve the existing value in _peopleCount when the check fails without setting it to nil? ie: returning nil, and leaving the value what it was?

Comment: @Sean check my comment above `var peopleCount: Int? { didSet { if let newValue = peopleCount, newValue > 0 { peopleCount = newValue } else { peopleCount = oldValue } } }`

Comment: you don't need a getter. just use didSet

Comment: @Sean check my updated answer, you can just delete the else branch. As already stated in my answer, you cannot return any values from a setter.

Comment: btw this would double your memory usage

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the idea, that's a better approach indeed, I don't see any reason for using the private backing variable in this simple case, so I included your approach in my answer.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks very much guys. I have implemented @LeoDabus 's idea. Working great.

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus but I think I can't make a struct a singleton? I need to use this class/struct to store global variables and helper functions. I'm looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788169/whats-the-difference-between-struct-based-and-class-based-singletons)